# Python: Read previous line and compare against current line

Tags: python, string, for-loop

Python noob using 2.7 on Windows. I'm working on making a hierarchy tree view in HTML programatically. I've got a file that is outputted similar to this:

```
0
  2
    4
      6
        8
        8
0
  2
    4
    4
      6
        8
        8
      6
      6
```

`out.txt` looks like this:

```
0
2
4
6
8
8
0
2
4
4
4
6
8
8
6
6
```

My code:

```
x = open('out.txt','r')

for current_line in x:
   prev_line = current_line[:-1]
   print "Current: " + current_line
   print "Previous: " + prev_line
   if prev_line > current_line:
       print "Folder"
   elif prev_line == current_line:
       print "Root"

x.close()
```

The problem I'm encountering is that each time I try to compare the `prev_line` to the `current_line` I do not get the desired output. I can do something like `if prev_line == "0": print "Root"` but that will not work as it is for only that case. Also, it seems like the `if` portion is being calculated before the next current is done. The results that I get from my current code includes:

```
Current: 0

Previous: 0
Current: 2

Previous: 2
Current: 4

Previous: 4
Current: 6

Previous: 6
Current: 8

Previous: 8
Current: 8

Previous: 8
Current: 0

Previous: 0
Current: 2

Previous: 2
Current: 4

Previous: 4
Current: 4

Previous: 4
Current: 4

Previous: 4
Current: 6

Previous: 6
Current: 8

Previous: 8
Current: 8

Previous: 8
Current: 6

Previous: 6
Current: 6
Previous:
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this? I don't know if this is a string vs int comparison but if it is I'm gonna feel dumb. I've tried it but it raises an error when checking the last "Previous:".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set prev_line to the value of current_line at the end of the for loop.

```
prev_line = ''

for current_line in x: 
   print "Current: " + current_line
   print "Previous: " + prev_line

   if prev_line > current_line:
       print "Folder"
   elif prev_line == current_line:
       print "Root"

    prev_line = current_line
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the next line? For example, I would like to check what the next letter will be. How would I implement this?

Comment: @serk that should be a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Your wrong declare prev_line. If current_line read as '0\n' so prev_line is '0'.
And prev_line never greater than current_line.
Try declare prev_line as full line.

```
prev_line = '0'

for current_line in x: 
    print "Current: " + current_line
    print "Previous: " + prev_line
    if prev_line > current_line:
        print "Folder"
    elif prev_line == current_line:
        print "Root"
    prev_line = current_line
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the next line? For example, I would like to check what the next letter will be. How would I implement this?

Comment: only next iteration in "for" cycle or readline from file, but it reduce readability of code. You can read whole file in list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code as:

```
x = open('out.txt','r') 
prev_line='0' 
for current_line in x:    
 print "Current: " + current_line    
 if prev_line != '': 
  print "Previous: " + prev_line    
 if prev_line > current_line:        
  print "Folder"    
 elif prev_line == current_line:        
  print "Root"  
 prev_line=current_line
x.close()
```

That should solve the issue. For the first line the current line is '0' but there is no previous line..so I guess it should print 'Root'. If my assumption is wrong then change prev_line='0' line to prev_line=''.

why not run a nested for loop and get the value of the next line. like declare num=1 at the start of the code and then ruun a nested for loop using.

```
x = open('out.txt','r') 
prev_line='0' 
num=1
for current_line in x:
 y=1
 for next_line in x:
  if y=num+1:
   nextline=next_line
  y+=1
 print "Next Line "+next_line
 num+=1
x.close()
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the next line? For example, I would like to check what the next letter will be. How would I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function I created:

```
def before(self):
    # get the current cursor position, then
    # store it in memory.
    current_position = self.tell()

    # move back by 1 byte at a time and store
    # that byte's contents into memory.
    _tmp = ""
    _rea = 0
    if "b" in self.mode:
        _tmp = b""

    while True:
        _rea += 1
        # move back x bits and read one byte
        self.handle.seek(current_position - _rea)

        # now we've read one byte
        _tmp += self.handle.read(1)

        # move back one byte again
        self.handle.seek(current_position - _rea)

        # If the string in memory contains the "\n"
        # EOL, we will return the string.

        # alternatively break if the current position
        # is zero.
        if _tmp.count("\n") == 2 or self.tell() == 0:
            break

    # somehow the string is reversed...
    return _tmp[::-1]
```

Where `self.handle` is a file object. Hope it helps!